# Nested mixins or functions in SASS

Tags: css, nested, sass, mixins

Some body know how can i use nested mixins or functions in SASS?
I have something like this:

```
@mixin A(){
    do something....
}

@mixin B($argu){
    @include A();
}
```

Comment: yeah you doing it right. You can call first mixin in second one. [check this pen](http://codepen.io/crazyrohila/pen/vuljA).

Comment: oh, thank you! i tried with this, but isnt working, maybe my ruby is crashing. I will try to re-install. Thank you. (codepen is amazing!, not yet known)

Comment: @crazyrohila You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Sorry I have deleted last pen by mistake. so created a new pen.

Comment: It's unclear here why running this code didn't answer your question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

yeah you already doing it right. You can call first mixin in second one. check this pen http://codepen.io/crazyrohila/pen/mvqHo

Answer (score 12):

You can multi nest mixins, you can also use place holders inside mixins..

```
@mixin a {
  color: red;
}
@mixin b {
  @include a();
  padding: white;
  font-size: 10px;
}
@mixin c{
  @include b;
  padding:5;
}
div {
  @include c();
}
```

which gives out CSS

```
div {
  color: red;
  padding: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 5;
}
```

Comment: It must be noted that order of mixin is important i.e. if you move `@mixin a{...}` at the bottom of above code, sass generate compile error `Undefined mixin 'a'`

Comment: any reason `b` is not `b()` in `@include b;` ?

Comment: @ajax333221 mixins don't HAVE to have parameters, if you don't specify params then the () are optional.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the other answers, you can include mixins in other mixins. In addition, you can scope your mixins.

**Example**

```
.menu {
  user-select: none;

  .theme-dark & {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;

    // Scoped mixin
    // Can only be seen in current block and descendants,
    // i.e., referencing it from outside current block
    // will result in an error.
    @mixin __item() {
      height: 48px;
    }

    &__item {
      @include __item();

      &_type_inverted {
        @include __item();

        color: #333;
        background-color: #fff;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Will output:

```
.menu {
  user-select: none;
}

.theme-dark .menu {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
}

.theme-dark .menu__item {
  height: 48px;
}

.theme-dark .menu__item_type_inverted {
  height: 48px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Scoping mixins means that you can have multiple mixins named the same in different scopes without conflicts arising.