# Combine raw selector with mixin into single query

Tags: sass

I have the following SASS rules:

```
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
  @include desktop() {
    p {
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
```

The mixin is like this:

```
@mixin desktop() {
  @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Elsewhere in the codebase there's a margin being set on desktop, hence in this case I need to explicitly remove it on the desktop breakpoint too, just having the first `p` selector rule doesn't cut it.

Is there a neat way to combine the selectors as it feels verbose having the same `margin: 0` rule twice?  I realise there's probably something more fundamentally wrong here with the inheritance, but that's outside the scope of the question.  I don't want to use `!important`.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a neat way to combine the selectors? Sure there is… Just use another mixin:

```
@mixin para {
    p {
        margin: 0;
    }
}

@include para;

@include desktop {
    @include para;
}
```

You clearly already know how to use mixins, so I'm assuming your question is really about whether you can nest one mixin within another ([yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020316/nested-mixins-or-functions-in-sass)), or whether you can include selectors within a mixin ([yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68464835/2652785)).